# Python mysql.connector insert does not work

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I work with the Python mysql.connector for the first time and I am not able to create a working insert statement.

This is the table:

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(255));'
```

I am trying to insert a variable as title while the id should be auto incremented. I have tried multiple solutions but it simply won't work.

```
def insert_product(title: str):
    insert_product_query = 'INSERT INTO products (title) VALUES (%s);'
    cursor.execute(insert_product_query, (title,))
```

This runs without any error, but the insert is not working. It does nothing. I tried multiple versions of this, with '?' instead of '%s' and without a tuple but it won't work.

Another solution I tried is this:

```
def insert_product(title: str):
    insert_product_query = f'INSERT INTO products (title) VALUES (\'{title}\')'
    print(insert_product_query)
    cursor.execute(insert_product_query)
```

I printed the insert statement and when I copy paste it directly into the database it works perfectly, so I don't have any idea why it is not working out of the python code as it is not producing any errors.

I found many similar problems but none of the solution worked for me.

I hope someone can help me as I might overlook something obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: le sigh. You didn't `commit` your changes :(

Comment: Your _first_ attempt is correct. Please don't go with the second, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's connector disables autocommit by default (as a reasonable library would do!). You need to explicitly commit after you perform a DML statement:

```
con.commit() # Assuming con is the name of the connection variable
```